# Node.js write object propertys in same time via socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, collision, async.js

In Node.js, can it happen that when different properties of a global object are written at the same time (with a socket.io request), one of the properties retains its original value?

`

```
var rooms = {
    a: {
      move: 1
    },
    b: {
      move: 2
    }
};

// it's called same time from different client with different room id
socket.on('onmove', function(data) {

    var room = rooms[data.room_id];

    room.move = data.move;
});
```

`

I tried to testing, but did not collide with each other.
However, I have an online game where the anomalies point to this.
The question is, is this theoretically possible? How are properties overwritten? Does one have an effect on the other?

Comment: Nodejs is running in one thread. Things are never happening in the same time

Comment: Theoretically no.

Comment: @KonradLinkowski not even in the case of a socket request? I think that maybe the second request uses the old properties because the first one hasn't been updated yet. I don't know exactly how works the object property updating, whether it affects the other props of the object. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs runs your Javascript in a single thread so no two requests are actually executing your Javascript at the exact same moment in time.  So, the code you show, all by itself, will not be susceptible to a race condition.

> The question is, is this theoretically possible?

No, not with just the code you show.  The `move` event handler will run to completion before any other requests or events can get called.

> How are properties overwritten? Does one have an effect on the other?

No.  Assigning to one property does not affect other properties.

---

That said, there are certainly concurrency-related things to be aware of in nodejs, particularly if a request handler is doing something asynchronous.  This is because, while it's waiting for some asynchronous completion callback to be called, other requests can run, change state, etc...  So, if one request handler grabs some state, then does something asynchronous and expects that state not to change while it's waiting for the asynchronous callback to be called, then it could lead to concurrency issues because other request handlers can run during that time and can affect server-side state.

Plus, there are many database operations that need to be coded carefully to avoid concurrency issues since two requests could be trying to make conflicting changes to the database or one request handler could grab some data, modify and write it back while another request handler is doing the same thing causing one request's changes to get overwritten.

So, if you suspect that this code is somehow involved in a concurrency issue, then I'd suggest you disclose a lot more related code so we can see if the way you've written the rest of the related code could lead to concurrency issues.